# Angular change detection ngFor

Tags: arrays, angular, data-binding, angular8, ngfor

I have an array called `peoples` on my tab view. I need to change the array items based on a change function. While the change function is working successfully and printing the array differently after each change on the console, the  view itself is not changing from the initial value assigned from `ngInit()`;

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.someservice.loadallpeople().subscribe(data=>{
    this.peoples=data.Data;
  });
}

loadpeople(category:any){
  this.someservice.getpeoplebycat(category).subscribe(data=>{
    this.peoples=data.Data;
  });
}
```

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="category.name"
        (ngModelChange)="loadpeople(category.name)">  
  <option *ngFor="let cat of category">{{category.name}} </option>
</select>  
    
<div *ngFor="let people of peoples">
  <span>{{people.name}}</span>
</div>
```

I have used some methods but none of them seems to work. Any small help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the `change()` function. How is it related to the `loadpeople()` function?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduction with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) ? Just like you show, it should work so there must be something wrong elsewhere

Comment: You don't unsubscribe from `loadallpeople`. It might be connected to that, in case also that observable emits a new value.

Comment: Have you tried https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectchanges?

Comment: @Aneesh have you found a solution for your issue ? Is mine working for you ?

Comment: yes, @Julian Liu, It is working fine thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things are not clear on what you show.

First you use `[(ngModel)]="category.name"` and `(ngModelChange)="loadpeople(category.name)"` on `category.name`, but next you iterate over `category` and you get `cat.name`, so there cannot be a `category.name` element if it's an array.

Second I will just use `(change)` instead of `[ngModel]` + `(ngModelChange)` according to what you show, because as said before, `category.name` cannot return anything.

So with all this updates, I will do something like this

```js
ngOnInit(){
  this.someservice.loadallpeople().subscribe(data=>{
    this.peoples=data.Data;
  });
}

loadpeople(event){
  this.someservice.getpeoplebycat(event.target.value).subscribe(data=>{
    this.peoples=data.Data;
  });
}
```

```html
<select (change)="loadpeople($event)">  
  <option *ngFor="let cat of category">{{cat.name}} </option>
</select>  
    
<div *ngFor="let people of peoples">
  <span>{{people.name}}</span>
</div>
```